# Help Diagnosing Engine -- Truck starts but won't run after repairs

Tags: engine, chevrolet, sparkplugs, muffler

Hoping for some help here. Very long story short, a spark plug wire was fouled in my '88 Chevy Scottsdale K1500, which was replaced. The spark plug was also replaced....but old wire was reattached, yet only on the end to the plug...so no spark. It was driven unknowing of this for around 65 miles. The result was unpleasant, as the muffler was blown out. Not just a hole, but blown out totally. The truck will still turn over and start and run, but only for a minute or so before dying again. The mistake with the plug/wire was mine, and don't worry.....I'm still kicking myself over it.

Any ideas or input as to why it won't stay running?

Comment: Is the exhaust sound extremely loud now?  You wouldn't happen to have a picture you post into your answer, would you?

Comment: Unfortunately, the truck is still about 75 miles away from where I am now. I was visiting friends when this happened. I'm in the process of trying to get it back up here to where I live. Let me contact my friends & see where it stands.

Comment: Stupid question ... are all of the wires hooked up correctly now? This is carbureted, right? I'd assume an HEI ignition (you might not know)? Will it run if you are pressing the gas pedal (revving the engine)?

Comment: From what I understand, the wires are hooked up and all the spark plugs have been taken out and cleaned. As for  being carbureted..... It's a 1988 with a 305 V8 in it, so yeah. They can get it started, but only for a minute before it died again. When I was with it last night, I started it once and gave it a little gas....and it died immediately. Almost puts me to mind of it being extremely flooded.

Comment: Sounds like there is a lot going on here than just a spark plug issue. What was going on before you had to change the spark plug wire? Was it running poorly? BTW, Paulster2's question about the being carbureted is valid since in 1988 Chevrolet K1500 trucks came with TBI (throttle body injection). Unless it was converted or engine was swapped, it is probably fuel injected. This is important to know when troubleshooting.

Comment: The plugs and wires were still pretty new, having been replaced less than a year ago. The issue with the one wire that had to be replaced, was that it wasn't tied up properly and had managed to touch the engine long enough to melt the coating and spark to the engine, causing a misfire. My horrendous mistake (made in a hurry) was that I reattached the old wire to the newly replaced plug....without the other end being put back on. A coworker suggested that the cylinder may be static or vapor locked, but without the truck up here to look at, it's tricky to say

Comment: As far as the truck running poorly beforehand, it wasn't running badly. I did tend to lose power going uphill. But other than that, no real issues.